# Flutter: When I get an error how do I remove items in the call stack that are not my code

Tags: flutter

in vscode when I get an error the call stack is filled with information that is not related to my code and I'm stuggling to get any use out of this. Below is a screen shot

[image]

I've scrolled to the bottom of this call stack and expand until I get to the bottom of the call stack (which takes 10 to 20 expanding clicks on the call stack). But I still cannot see anything that relates to my code.

Seems like i must be missing something simple here. How do I find the my code that is creating the issue? I was thinking that filtering would be helpful but even when expanding I don't see anything that relates to my code.

Comment: Have you checked the problems tab?

Comment: Yer checked problems tab.
looking at it again looks like an issue with provider "_TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double?')"
I have 
GenericSidePanelState(panelType: ContourThematicPanelType.meticDisplay, width: 440.0);

but if I have (note removing the ".0" on the width. 
GenericSidePanelState(panelType: ContourThematicPanelType.meticDisplay, width: 440); 

Then it throws the above error. 
But doesn't actually tell me where the error is coming from.

Comment: I see, I dont think you can remove them, have you tried running the project without debugging?